# OPENGL, gluProject returns FAIL, why?

Tags: opengl

The gluProject() always returns GLU_FAIL. Could somebody tell me why?

(Code):

```
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble viewVector[3];
GLdouble projection[16];
GLdouble winX, winY, winZ;//2D point
GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;//3D point
posX=k;
posY=0.0;
posZ=0.0;

glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection  );
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

int res=gluProject(posX,posY,posZ,modelview,projection,viewport,&winX,&winY,&winZ);
```

edit @ 2014/01/27:

I have found the reason causing this error. It's because both glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection ) and glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview ) return null matrix. But I still don't know how to fix this bug. 
Why do the two function can't return the true result matrix? Thank you all.

Comment: Could someone give me a help?

Comment: Which version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: What's the value of `GLU_FAIL`?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one reason this would fail, and that is if the math would have resulted in a division by zero.

Your coordinates start out in object-space, are transformed into view-space by multiplying by your ModelView matrix, then into clip-space by multiplying by Projection. The next thing that happens is that each component of the resulting 4D vector is divided by its W component to produce Normalized Device Coordinates, and ***this*** is where the function may return `GLU_FALSE`.

If your clip-space W coordinate is **0.0**, it will fail. It is impossible to say why your clip-space W is **0.0** without seeing your actual matrices, but this is the one and only reason for this function to return `GLU_FALSE`.

Comment: I have found the reason causing this error. It's because both glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection  ); and glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview ); return null matrix. But I still don't know how to fix this bug. Why do the two function can't return the true result matrix? Thank you all.